# Move duplicated CmakeLists.txt functionality to a common file

Tags: cmake

I have multiple projects that have identical/duplicated code in their respective CMakeLists.txt. At the very least I need a place to store string definitions that I can pull into the CMakeLists.txt files. What's the best way to do this? My directory structure

```
common_defs/
        src_files
        hdr_files
        CMakeLists.Txt  - file that has common defs
independent_dir1/
        src_files
        hdr_files
        CMakeLists.Txt  --> Imports/Includes from ../common_defs/CMakeLists.txt
independent_dir2/
        src_files
        hdr_files
        CMakeLists.Txt  --> Imports/Includes from ../common_defs/CMakeLists.txt
```

independent_dir1 and independent_dir2 will be built independently from each other. Building in common_defs should not trigger builds in the independent_dirs

Comment: Explore `add_subdirectory` and related functions.

Comment: `add_subdirectory` doesn't quite get me there, because I need independent builds.

Comment: use `include` to include common cmake code. But honestly, i think we dont entirely understand your problem. What do you mean with _pull_?

Comment: `include` will do it. WRT "pull" I'm not sure what to call it, I can see why it's confusing. I mean that the independent_dir*/CMakeLists files should include/import the common code from the common_defs/CMakeLists.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in `common_defs/common_defs.cmake` with common strings and definitions, than add to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
// add path common_defs to include search path
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../common_defs")
// include module from file common.cmake searched in search path
include(common_defs)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot now, and mark the answer appropriately.